# CSS Vertical align to middle

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I know this issue was discussed many times before. but honestly I didn't find any proper solution for this unique case:

I have the following HTML code:

```
 <div class="print-types-links">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <div> 
                    <span>aaa</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <div>
                    <span>bbb</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.print-types-links li{
list-style: none;

}
.print-types-links ul{
    padding: 0;
}
.print-types-links a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
.print-types-links div:hover{
    background-color:#F7FAFF;
}
.print-types-links div{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#EAF2FD;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}

.print-types-links span{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

and I'm trying to vertical-align the `<span>` inside the `<div>`.

Required result I wish for: **the text should be in middle of each box.**
I know I can do it with specify pixel number. but i'm trying to avoid it.

I also tried using `vertical-align:middle` in the `span` and the parent `div` without any success.

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/zo04s8q7/) for the issue.

Thank you.

Comment: If `vertical-align: middle` does not work the problem might be related to the height of the surrounding div.

Comment: @grc the text should be in the middle of each box.

Comment: @Koogle I checked the height using chrome dev tool. looks good for me. You can see yourself using fiddle link I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `padding-bottom: 60px;` property in the div that's why div is not vertically aligned .
You can use the above  property like `padding-top: 30px;` , `padding-bottom: 30px` than the div is vertically aligned.

Please refer the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vq9nek8t/)

**CSS:**

```
.print-types-links div{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#EAF2FD;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't figured that padding is the issue :P

Comment: This is the perfect solution if you have only one line of text.  If you have multiple lines, the `div`'s height will grow due to the padding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set there `display: table/table-cell` property to `div`s and `span`s. Then don't forget to remove bottom padding for `div`.

```
.print-types-links div {
    padding-bottom: 0; 
    display: table; 
    width: 100%; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    height: 100px;
 }

.print-types-links span {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zo04s8q7/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try with padding : `padding:30px 0px;`. Give 30px top and bottom. It will align your text to the middle

```
.print-types-links div{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #EAF2FD;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding:30px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`line-height` is the key to making `vertical-align` work:

```
.print-types-links div{
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
}

.print-types-links span{
    line-height: 1.2em;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

### Fiddle